# Gallery app not showing to upload image from gallery

Tags: javascript, android, imagepicker

I want to pick image from gallery and then crop it to make profile image, I am using library to crop it but when I click to upload image it shows only camera to upload image not gallery. Below is my code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4dey.png)

Comment: Please add some code!

Comment: What library you are using? What have you done so far? Please be more specific